# No sound with Jitsi Meet and ALSA

Tags: chromium, alsa, compute-module-3

For a project I'm using a Raspberry Pi with ALSA. ALSA is configured and `speaker-test` provides me audio output. However, when I open Jitsi Meet in Chromium, there is no sound. When I open YouTube in Chromium, there is sound. Does anybody have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is Jitsi Meet?

Comment: "Jitsi Meet" is a video conferencing system.

Comment: Is this a Raspberry Pi question?